# Is it possible to have less dyads then triangles in a graph?

Tags: graph, networkx

I don't really know where to post this question, but I am analyzing a graph, and I do not understand my results. I suspect something to be wrong with either my code or with my interpretation of the output.

So, I have a graph constructed in Python using `NetworkX`. I am examining homophily within the network. Therefore I want to analyse the clustering, dyads, etc.

What I don't understand I how it is possible that I find that there are more triangles than dyads, as every triangle consists of three `dyads` **I find 1,325,215 triangles but only 189,464 dyads** (this is even before dividing the number of `dyads` by 2).

Can someone elaborate as to what my mistake is or how my understanding of these concepts is wrong?

I need to count the number of triangles. As such I use the 'nx.triangles' function and compute this with the following code:

```
triangles = sum(nx.triangles(G).values()) // 3
```

I also want to know the number of `dyads` (connected pairs of nodes). I do this with the following code:

```
def count_dyads(G): dyad_count = 0

for node in G: neighbors = set(G.neighbors(node)) for neighbor in neighbors: dyad_count += 1

return dyad_count
```

I understand that each pair is counted twice so I divide th`e dyad` count by 2 to get the number of connected pairs.